# $U \subseteq W \implies W^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

$U \subseteq W \implies W^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$
Question regarding this:
My exerciser at the study did this proof while assuming this:
$U+W=R^n$, so, need to prove: $U^\perp+W^\perp=R^n$. and that prove the problem at the post.
Why is it like that? and how should I think that if I see such a thing, I need to prove something  else for it? and why proving this is equal?

Comment: $>>$ means $\implies$ in this context, yes?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think, yea, its a: if, so thingy.

Comment: it seems like $U,W$ are subsets of $R^m$ and your instructor was identifying $U+W$ with $R^n$ for some $n\leq m$. In general, if $U\subseteq W\subseteq R^m$, we do not have $U + W = R^m$. In fact, $\dim(U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim(U\cap W)$.

Comment: Ahh, I guess he mixed proofs or something then.. sorry for the confusion, Thanks anyway :)

Comment: In regards to the complementary relations, we know that $W^{\perp} = \{x : <x, y> = 0 \forall y \in W\}$ for instance (that is the definition you're using right?), in which case if $U \subseteq W$ then if $x \in W^{\perp}$ that means for any $y \in U$ since $y \in W$ this means that $<x, y> = 0$ and so $<x, y> = 0$ for all $y \in U$ and so $x \in U^{\perp} \implies W^{\perp} \subseteq U^{\perp} $

Comment: As for the subspace decomposition thingy I'm not sure what exactly you're saying, but it sounds like you're using the fact that if $U + W = R^n$ then $U \cap W = \{0\}$ and so leveraging the inclusion relations (with a bit of tweaking) we can conclude that $U^{\perp} \cap W^{\perp} = \{0\}$ . But in any case we're being a bit imprecise here as I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say

Comment: Thank you :) I did something similliar to in to be honest, I wanted to see if the proof he did was related, which was weird to me, I guess he just wrote 2 proofs in instance ( not very organized :\ ). Thank!

Comment: Yea, you said right, he assumed that also, just like you said.